# Getting class method argument types from indexed generic type

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a class with some functions as well as a non-function property:

```
class Example {
    methodA(param1: string, param2: number) {}
    methodB(): string {}
    methodC(param1: boolean, param2: number): number {}
    prop1: string = '';
}
```

I want to write a method that would receive the class method name as a parameter and the corresponding method's arguments as the remaining parameters and also return the same data type as the specified class method. It would look like this:

```
call('methodA', 'a string', 123); // If the method has a void return type
let value = call('methodC', true, 456) // If the method has a non-void return type;
```

I can fetch the method names using `keyof Example` as follows:

```
function call<K extends keyof Example>(functionName: K) {}
```

However, I am stuck at getting the corresponding method arguments and return type. My attempt has been as follows:

```
function call<K extends keyof Example>(functionName: K, ...args: Parameters<Example[K]>): ReturnType<Example[K]>
```

When I do this, I get an error stating that `Type 'Example[K]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'`.

When I use the indexed type on its own and without using the rest parameters

```
function call<K extends keyof Example>(functionName: K, args: Example[K])...
```

I can see that the correct function signature is expected as the args parameters, so I assumed that this function type satisfy the constraint expected by the Parameters<> utlity type. I have a similar issue with the ReturnType utility type.

How could I get `Example[K]` to work as `(...args: any) => void`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Unfortunately [I cannot reproduce your problem](https://tsplay.dev/NVR1GN).  Could you make sure that you are providing a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when someone copies and pastes it into a standalone IDE?  (Guess: perhaps `Example` has *non-function properties*?  If so, you should show that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my issue, the problem was that the class I was using also contained public variables/properties and these are picked up by the `keyof Example` type. When using this in a `Parameters<>` type, it throws an error because not all the class properties are callable.

The solution was to enclose the `keyof Example` inside an `Exclude<>` utility type and specify which keys need to be excluded.

For example, if the class was declared as follows:

```
class Example {
    public prop1: string = '';

    methodA(param1: string, param2: number) {}
    methodB(): string {}
    methodC(param1: boolean, param2: number): number {}
}
```

then callable keys can be obtained using `Exclude<keyof Example, 'prop1'>` resulting in `Parameters<Exclude<keyof Example, 'prop1'>>` being valid.

Comment: This solution only works if you know in advance which property names are non-method names, but if so, you might as well just write `"methodA" | "methodB" | "methodC"` instead of using `keyof Example` at all.  Presumably you want to *programmatically* determine the method names from `Example`, right?  Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 0):

You want to get just the keys of `Example` whose property values are callable.  There is no built-in utility type that does this for you (see [microsoft/TypeScript#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992) for the relevant feature request) but you can define your own in a number of ways.  Here's one way, using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as):

```
type KeysMatching<T extends object, V> = keyof { 
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: any 
}
```

So `KeysMatching<T, V>` will give you just those keys of `T` whose property values are assignable to `V`.  And so you can get just the callable keys of `Example` like this:

```
type CallableKeys = KeysMatching<Example, (...args: any) => any>;
// type CallableKeys = "methodA" | "methodB" | "methodC"
```

Now you can then define `call()` in terms of `CallableKeys`:

```
declare function call<K extends CallableKeys>(
    functionName: K, ...args: Parameters<Example[K]> // okay
): ReturnType<Example[K]>;
```

and the error goes away.

This approach has the advantage of automatically updating if more non-function properties are added to the `Example` class.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwKIA8oFsAOECA3gFDznw4gAuAFgPbACCAFHrLgIwBc8y1MAJYA7AOYAaeOxi4ATL2EBXHACMQMAJS8AbvUHAA3GQpU6jAEIstfASNFGKlGg2ABhNhxw94K+vUJQwpLScgrKapphquoOFHgw9Hje-EJiRgC+JCTUAJ54CADSIDnIALJQ1GC0dgA8ACrwIJjUIMLAaPQqAFbg1JIAagB88AC88ADWxfQAZvCkjgDaBfAiE1OzDSjwdUsAuo3Nre3w-fAA-PDLCiDa6ru8gTkkmdl5CK5QENAqhEUlo5dimUKlValhcAQQJIWAA6OGwUTIB7CHIaUbDR6DIwAemx8Fy+XgHy+UB+ID+aDGACJTC4mFT4AAfeA05wWBnM1lmNxUrKgJBweDTRTCMDUQT0YSIT4QGrLJotNpoYnfX5AwYsYzkYWi8WSgByuBAvAKkjhMIRSPgAAVPDR1MgauD8IQ9oMSNYAEo0RQwYR1N5O7AukBuoxZEhAA)